# Class import into Vue component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to make separate class for axios requests, which works like "service"

Vue component:

```
<template>
    <div v-for="user in users">
        {{ user.firstname }} - {{ user.lastname }} - {{ user.middlename }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ConnectionService from './ConnectionService';
    const connectionService = new ConnectionService();

    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component is mounted');
        },

        created() {
            this.users = connectionService.getSingleInstance('http://laravelapi/user');
            console.log("This are users " + this.users);
        },

        data() {
            return {
                users: [],
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the service is the following:

```
export default class ConnectionService {

    getSingleInstance(path) {
        console.log('This is path ' + path);

        let axios_data = {};
        axios.get(path).then(response => axios_data = response.data.result);

        console.log('This is data ' + axios_data);
        console.log(axios_data);

        return axios_data;
    }


}
```

As I can see in my console, I get the data from axios xhr request, but then they are not passed to the Vue Component, because I get empty object in the string                 console.log("This are users " + this.users);

How to import COnnectionService properly and then use it in Vue Component?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the next in your vue component:

```
created() {
    connectionService.getSingleInstance('http://laravelapi/user')
        .then(function(response){
            this.users = response
            console.log("This are users " + this.users);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error)
        });
}
```

Like getSingleInstance returns an object I recommend declaring user like this: `user: Object` or `user: {}` instead `user: []`

It seems that you have to use promises because `.get` is an async function. To install Q promises package see: [Q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q)

How to use in your example:

```
import Q from 'q'

export default class ConnectionService {
    getSingleInstance(path) {
        var deferred = Q.defer()
        console.log('This is path ' + path);

        axios.get(path)
            .then(
                 function(response) {
                     deferred.resolve(response.data.result)
                 },
                 function(error){
                     deferred.reject(error)
                 })
        return deferred.promise
    }
}
```

As you can see I have changed the arrow syntax (`=>`) because I clarify more like this.

I can not test it and I'm not an expert (I just try to help) but I think it should work.

Comment: Tried to do this, but got the following error: app.js:34877 [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: connectionService.getSingleInstance(...).then is not a function"

Comment: @ILya I edited my answer (I don't know if it will work) but in any case I think it is a problem due to the asynchronous function and you can look for information about it to solve it.